# Unit testing with flutter scoped model

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, scoped-model

Developing an app I end up with some logic in my scoped model. My search does not show any examples on unit testing. Does anyone have an experience with in writing a test for scoped model? How can I mock lifecycle of the scoped model?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of what you mean by the lifecycle...

But if you want to test Model startup, state changes and rebuilds of widgets (via Scoped Model) you should have a look at the actual unit tests of the Scoped Model repository.

Some good examples in there...

[Scoped Model's unit tests](https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/blob/master/test/scoped_model_test.dart)